# How to convert time string value in date format

Tags: java, date, time, seconds, datetime-parsing

I am facing issue like I have a datasheet which have a string value like 123459 which is a time and I have another column where I am adding in value as plus 5 seconds.
When I am adding value its add as 123464 instead of 123504.
Could anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse clock time in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870160/parse-clock-time-in-java-8). Or of [How to format a double value as time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092348/how-to-format-a-double-value-as-time).

Comment: I did not downvote. In case you were wondering about the downvotes and the votes to close, I suspect they are because you don’t show any search and research effort nor any attempt to solve your problem yourself. You’re supposed to do that. And it generally gives us a better starting point for helping you, so it’ll be to your own advantage.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Specifically, the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) classes.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("123459", formatter);

LocalTime timeIn5Seconds = localTime.plusSeconds(5);
System.out.println(timeIn5Seconds.format(formatter));
```

#### Output

```
123504
```

Answer (score 0):

to convert string to date format...

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");

Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
```

to add 5 seconds

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
cal.setTime(date); // sets calendar time/date according to the OBJECT

cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5); // adds 5 SECONDS
cal.getTime();
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated (along with `Calendar` and `date`), it is also notoriously troublesome. And today we have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).